# How to disable the cancel button of alert box in Edge browser

Tags: javascript

Any one please help me in controlling the  "X" (cancel Button) of alert box in edge browser, Either i have to remove it or i have to get the click event.[image]

Comment: Not possible, it's a native dialog, you can't fork it. Create your own alert dialog (or pick a one from the thousands of the libraries) if you need to control it ... Actually, why? The OK button in an alert dialog does exactly the same as the close button ... it just closes the box.

Comment: You want to remove the ability of the user to close the dialog? Why will the browser allow you that?

Comment: The ok button and the close button are giving different results for me thats why i asked. Or as you suggest,  i may have to use other alert dialog. Thanks...

Comment: _“The ok button and the close button are giving different results for me thats why i asked.”_ - what “results” are you talking about …?

Comment: `alert()` will return `undefined` despite of how you're closing the dialog. Introducing your real problem here might save you a lot of work, what is the real problem in this case?

Comment: Sujesh, **please read**: [What should you do when someone answers your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

By a native dialog-boxes it isn't possible.

Other site you don't need it because the OK button has the same function like the close button in this dialog-box: in both ways the dialog-box will be closed and nothing else.

But if you want to control it you can create your own alert dialog-box. Or you can use some library or framework with custom dialog-boxes.